# Copies of plist created in app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plist, nsuserdefaults, dropbox

I am storing data in `NSUserdefaults` , there are however multiple copies of `plists` in the `.xcappdata` and this causes my app to balloon (possibly after every run) .

The copies have various extensions to them: (.plist.c1veawh ,  .plist.IJQRirI and many more) .

The one without any extension (only .plist ) is about 13.3 mb and the rest have descending sizes.

Could this be because I am building my app from a `Dropbox` directory and the app picks up some backup version of them ?

I only access the plist through `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and synchronise after edits.

I have no issues accessing the `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` but the app should be under 20mb is now over 400mb.

Part of a Snapshot of the `.xcappdata` > show package contents > App data > Library > Preferences [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X89Nk.png)

Comment: So the binaries are being built into a directory managed by Dropbox?  If so, that's a terrible idea.

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe , I guess I'll move it out . Any recommendations for auto-backups ( version control is not a necessity ) . Or rather , can I shift some file locations out of Dropbox to make work ?

Comment: I also use `git`.  No exceptions for anything worth keeping.